# How can I modify a private variable from another class?

Tags: java, object, graph, private, shuffle

I'm writing code for an assignment and I am given a class written by my teacher which has a public constructor. However, the variables in the constructor are private. I am trying to shuffle an object's array but because it's private, I am unable to modify it. If I am unable to modify the code my teacher wrote is there any way to do this?

This is the constructor and variables from my teacher's class:

```
private final int V;
private int E;
private Bag<Integer>[] adj;

/**
 * Initializes an empty graph with <tt>V</tt> vertices and 0 edges.
 * param V the number of vertices
 * @throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException if <tt>V</tt> < 0
 */
public Graph(int V) {
    if (V < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number of vertices must be nonnegative");
    this.V = V;
    this.E = 0;
    adj = (Bag<Integer>[]) new Bag[V];
    for (int v = 0; v < V; v++) {
        adj[v] = new Bag<Integer>();
    }
}
```

This is the method I am making:

```
public boolean tryImprove(double secs) {
    int size = G.V(); //V() returns the number of vertices of the graph
    Graph gTemp = G;
    Bag<Integer>[] adj = new Bag[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        adj[i] = (Bag<Integer>) G.adj(i);
    }
    gTemp.adj = adj; //this is where I'm having trouble with the private array
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() <= secs) {
        gTemp.adj = shuffle(adj, size);
        this.color = greedyColoring(gTemp);
        if (maxColor < greedyMax) return true;
    }
    // TODO: implement some graph coloring heuristic here.
    // Minimal good enough: do repeated trials of greedy-coloring,
    // each time with a random vertex order.  If you find a better
    // coloring (better than your previous best), return true.  Or
    // else if you run out of time, return false.

    // Note you can use System.currentTimeMillis() to estimate how
    // much time you have used.  For an example of its use, see
    // the code in main.

    return false;
}
```

adj(int v) method (in teacher's class):

```
public Iterable<Integer> adj(int v) {
    validateVertex(v);
    return adj[v];
}
```

greedyColoring(Graph G) method (written by teacher, can't change):

```
private static int[] greedyColoring(Graph G)
{
    int V = G.V();
    assert V >= 1;
    // This will be our coloring array.
    int[] color = new int[V];
    // In loop, we keep track of the maximum color used so far.
    int maxColor = 0;
    // For each vertex v, we let color[v] be the first color which
    // is not already taken by the neighbors of v.
    for (int v=0; v<V; ++v) {
        boolean[] taken = new boolean[maxColor+1];
        for (int u: G.adj(v))
            taken[color[u]] = true;
        // Find the first color c not taken by neighbors of v.
        int c = 1;
        while (c <= maxColor && taken[c])
            ++c;
        color[v] = c;
        // Maybe we started using a new color at v.
        if (c > maxColor)
            maxColor = c;
    }

    // All done, return the array.
    return color;
}
```

If there is no way to shuffle the object's private array does anyone have a suggestion on how I could call greedyColoring on the graph object with a shuffled index (not sure if I phrased that correctly)?

Thanks!

Comment: Here are two hints: `public void setBag(Bag<Integer>[] adj) this.adj = adj;` and `graph.setBag(ValueToBeSet);`. To make it simpler, **`setter`** methods is what you are looking for.

Comment: Add a setter method, but if you can't do that then you _can_ do it with reflection.

Comment: @JaskaranbirSingh Can I use the setter method in my class or does it have to be in the class with the private variable?

Comment: @jonk I looked up reflection but what I've found has a lot of terms I haven't learned yet, is there anywhere that has basic information on it?

Comment: Setter method has to be in class with private variable. Because thats the whole purpose, nothing can access the private variable unless its in the same class. So we create a method that can be accessed by anyone within that class so that method can change the variable's value. And @jonk, I dont think we should really be mentioning reflection at this point. He seems to be new to java. Lets leave that for later ;)